# htaccess issue: if else conditions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to make if else in htaccess. Here the condition and I wanted to convert it to htaccess

url link in address bar that a visitor might type are these:

- w/o segments = www.myshopname.com/
- w/ segments = www.myshopname.com/category/1/cars

---

```
if(there's a segments){
    //it will use this rewriterule
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/shop/myshopname/$1 [P] 
}
else{ 
    //or this rewriterule
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/shop/myshopname [P] 
}
```

as you can see there will be $1 if there is a segment.

Currently my codes are in this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myshopname\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/shop/myshopname [P]
```

and if I add /$1 (http://www.example.com/shop/myshopname/$1) the browser sends an error of "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Comment: look at this example sure it will help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906060/is-there-a-way-to-if-else-a-rewrite-in-apache-htaccess

Comment: You're not the first person who face this task. There's a very common and know solution known as "Front Controller". Which you can find in any php-framework

Comment: @AghaUmairAhmed yup i saw that one but I would need to check if there is a segments  (ex. /category/1/cars)

Comment: @bad_boy what do you mean of "front controller" this uses the  codeigniter framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one rule for both conditions since `$1` will be empty for landing page:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myshopname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.example.com/shop/wish-you-have/$1?shop_link=wish-you-have [P,L]
```

Comment: hmm thanks but, i receive this error "This rule was met, the new url is http://www.myshopname.com/
The tests are stopped, using a different host will cause a redirect" (http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: should my code look like this?:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myshopname\.com
# with segments
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.example.com/shop/myshopname/$1[P]

# without segments
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.example.com/shop/myshopname/ [P]

Comment: myshopname.com is from a different domain not in example.com (ecommerce shop like volusion)

I'm having a problem in pull the contents of homepage and innerpage because there was a confilict if I use $1

myshopname.com just pulls the contents in example.com/shop/myshopname/

Comment: I've updated and used your suggested code but the homepage (www.myshopname.com) follows the with segment rule... i tried to remove the $1 in w/o segement rule and the homepage work but the inner pages didn't...checkout this http://www.wishyouhave.com/category/190

Comment: How is looking at `http://www.wishyouhave.com/category/190` proving rule is working or not? You need to show your full & latest .htaccess in question for that.

Comment: sure, there i've updated to latest htaccess in the question. I added ?shop_link... because system check if the custom url is valid

Comment: But now it seems you don't even need 2 rules since `http://www.viicart.com/shop/wish-you-have/$1?shop_link=wish-you-have` is same as `http://www.viicart.com/shop/wish-you-have/?shop_link=wish-you-have` when `$1` is also empty.

Comment: yup that's what I did last time but i try to remove the $1 to make it work and I thought that making some condition that would separate the rewriterule for with segments would work...